# Pandas Mask, GroupBy and CumSum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How can i do a rolling sum of the column `Trade_Cost` when the column `Buy(C)/Sell(V)` is `C` and reset this sum every time `Current_Qntd` hits `0`, and then start a new rolling sum until the next `zero`?

```
     Buy(C)/Sell(V)   Qntd     Price  Current_Qntd    Trade_Cost
0               C  33000  103.980000         33000  3.431340e+06
1               C   3682  102.940000         36682  3.790251e+05
2               C    108  103.490000         36790  1.117692e+04
3               C  10717  103.500000         47507  1.109210e+06
4               C   6831  103.760000         54338  7.087846e+05
5               C    968  107.000000         55306  1.035760e+05
6               C     32  107.000000         55338  3.424000e+03
7               V   3644  115.618296         51694  4.213131e+05
8               V   4704  115.995689         46990  5.456437e+05
9               V  46990  116.030000             0  5.452250e+06
10              C  35000  116.000000         35000  4.060000e+06
11              C  16000  117.999073         51000  1.887985e+05
12              V   1200  115.274742         49800  1.383297e+05
13              V   1400  116.700036         48400  1.633800e+05
14              V  23855  116.406567         24545  2.776879e+06
15              V   2589  116.247625         21956  3.009651e+05
16              V  12741  115.952801          9215  1.477355e+06
17              V   9132  115.951078            83  1.058865e+06
18              V     83  115.950000             0  9.623850e+03
```

**EDIT:**

I got the answer bellow from another question i posted here on StackOverflow, but it doesnt suit my need because i have many assets on this df, and the example above is just for one asset.

```
grp = (df['Current_Qntd'] == 0).cumsum()

df['Trade_Cost Sum'] = df['Trade_Cost'].mask(df['Buy(C)/Sell(V)'] != 'C', 0)

df['Trade_Cost Sum'] = df.groupby(grp)['Trade_Cost Sum'].cumsum()
```

The answer above works fine for a DF with just one asset, but I would need to group by asset in a DF with many assets. Bellow is the continuation of the above DF but with two assets

```
Buy(C)/Sell(V)  Qntd       Price  Current_Qntd     Trade_Cost    Asset
0                C   100  114.290000           100   11429.000000    2
1                C  3137  115.020000          3237  360817.740000    2
2                V   100  114.500000          3137   11450.000000    2
3                V  1200  114.670000          1937  137604.000000    2
4                V  1937  115.000000             0  222755.000000    2
5                C  5586   96.790000          5586  540668.940000    2
6                V  5586  116.590000             0  651271.740000    2
7                C   971  118.630000           971  115189.730000    2
8                V   971  129.800000             0  126035.800000    2
9                C   600  126.416417           600   75849.850002    2
10               C  33000  103.980000         33000  3.431340e+06    1
11               C   3682  102.940000         36682  3.790251e+05    1
12               C   108  103.490000         36790  1.117692e+04     1
13               C  10717  103.500000         47507  1.109210e+06    1
14               C   6831  103.760000         54338  7.087846e+05    1
15               C    968  107.000000         55306  1.035760e+05    1
16               C     32  107.000000         55338  3.424000e+03    1
17               V   3644  115.618296         51694  4.213131e+05    1
18               V   4704  115.995689         46990  5.456437e+05    1
19               V  46990  116.030000             0  5.452250e+06    1
20               C 35000  116.000000         35000  4.060000e+06     1
21               C 16000  117.999073         51000  1.887985e+06     1
22               V  1200  115.274742         49800  1.383297e+05     1
23               V  1400  116.700036         48400  1.633800e+05     1
24               V 23855  116.406567         24545  2.776879e+06     1
25               V  2589  116.247625         21956  3.009651e+05     1
26               V 12741  115.952801          9215  1.477355e+06     1
27               V  9132  115.951078            83  1.058865e+06     1
28               V    83  115.950000             0  9.623850e+03     1
```

**EDIT 2:**

`grp = (df['Current_Qntd'] == 0).cumsum()` is grouping 2 different assets with current_qntd = 0, how can i group it by asset too?

Comment: Throw 'Asset' in along with `grp`: `df.groupby(['Asset', grp])...`

Comment: Your question makes it sound more complicated than it is. `Current_Qntd` goes to 0 whenever a group has `Buy(C)/Sell(V)` == `V`, so  just figure out your groupby() by some list of columns.

Comment: I added the Asset on the groupby as @QuangHoang said, but it is not doing the cumsum  correctly after the Current_Qntd hits zero

Comment: @smci I believe that there is a problem with `grp = (df['Current_Qntd'] == 0).cumsum()`, because when i add it as a column and filter the column by grp, i see diferent assets with the same grp number

Comment: Then you have to `groupby(['Asset', grp], ...)` as QuangHoang said. When you say *"but it is not doing the cumsum correctly after the Current_Qntd hits zero"* please show the output and explain exactly why it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Then you just group by the column you just created *and* the asset, no?

```py
grp = (df['Current_Qntd'] == 0).cumsum()

df['Trade_Cost Sum'] = df['Trade_Cost'].mask(df['Buy(C)/Sell(V)'] != 'C', 0)

df['Trade_Cost Sum'] = df.groupby(["Asset", grp])['Trade_Cost Sum'].cumsum()
```

Produces this:

```
   Buy(C)/Sell(V)   Qntd       Price  ...    Trade_Cost  Asset  Trade_Cost Sum
0               C    100  114.290000  ...  1.142900e+04      2    1.142900e+04
1               C   3137  115.020000  ...  3.608177e+05      2    3.722467e+05
2               V    100  114.500000  ...  1.145000e+04      2    3.722467e+05
3               V   1200  114.670000  ...  1.376040e+05      2    3.722467e+05
4               V   1937  115.000000  ...  2.227550e+05      2    0.000000e+00
5               C   5586   96.790000  ...  5.406689e+05      2    5.406689e+05
6               V   5586  116.590000  ...  6.512717e+05      2    0.000000e+00
7               C    971  118.630000  ...  1.151897e+05      2    1.151897e+05
8               V    971  129.800000  ...  1.260358e+05      2    0.000000e+00
9               C    600  126.416417  ...  7.584985e+04      2    7.584985e+04
10              C  33000  103.980000  ...  3.431340e+06      1    3.431340e+06
11              C   3682  102.940000  ...  3.790251e+05      1    3.810365e+06
12              C    108  103.490000  ...  1.117692e+04      1    3.821542e+06
13              C  10717  103.500000  ...  1.109210e+06      1    4.930752e+06
14              C   6831  103.760000  ...  7.087846e+05      1    5.639537e+06
15              C    968  107.000000  ...  1.035760e+05      1    5.743113e+06
16              C     32  107.000000  ...  3.424000e+03      1    5.746537e+06
17              V   3644  115.618296  ...  4.213131e+05      1    5.746537e+06
18              V   4704  115.995689  ...  5.456437e+05      1    5.746537e+06
19              V  46990  116.030000  ...  5.452250e+06      1    0.000000e+00
20              C  35000  116.000000  ...  4.060000e+06      1    4.060000e+06
21              C  16000  117.999073  ...  1.887985e+06      1    5.947985e+06
22              V   1200  115.274742  ...  1.383297e+05      1    5.947985e+06
23              V   1400  116.700036  ...  1.633800e+05      1    5.947985e+06
24              V  23855  116.406567  ...  2.776879e+06      1    5.947985e+06
25              V   2589  116.247625  ...  3.009651e+05      1    5.947985e+06
26              V  12741  115.952801  ...  1.477355e+06      1    5.947985e+06
27              V   9132  115.951078  ...  1.058865e+06      1    5.947985e+06
28              V     83  115.950000  ...  9.623850e+03      1    0.000000e+00
```

Note that the Trade Cost Sum in row 10 is the same as the Trade Cost for that row, so the cumulative sum is correctly being reset.

Comment: I believe that there is a problem with `grp = (df['Current_Qntd'] == 0).cumsum()`, because when i add it as a column and filter the column by grp, i see diferent assets with the same grp number